# Covering space of a CW is also a CW , case of finite sheets

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, covering-spaces, cw-complexes

I have seen some answers online regarding this but I wanted to make sure that my proof was correct. I believe this only works if we assume that we have a finite sheeted covering

Now we wish to see why a covering space of a CW complex is also a CW complex. For the $0$-cells of $p:E\rightarrow B$ take them to be the pre-image under $p$ of the $0$-cells of $B$. For the $1$-cells notice that a $1$-cell of $B$ is a map $\phi: I\rightarrow B$ and by the unique lifting property, for each $x\in p^{-1}(b)$ we can find a a lift $\tilde \phi $ starting at $x$. Now for the characteristic maps of dimension $n\geq 2$ we can just use the unique sphere filling property. Now the tricky part is to check that the topology on $E$ is the weak topology. If we take an open set $A$ in the initial topology of $E$ we will have by continuity that it's pre-image by any characteristic map will be open, and so this tells us that $A$ is open in the weak topology.Now take a set $A$ open in the weak topology and we wish to show that it's open.For this we need only to check that $A\cap p^{-1}(U)$ is open for every evenly covered neighborhood $U$. We know that $p^{-1}(U)\cong \cup_i U_i$ with each $U_i$ projecting homeomorphically to $U$. Notice that the set $p(A)\cap U$ is open in $B$ since $A$ is open in the weak topology of $E$ and by definition of a lift $\tilde \phi$ we have that $\phi=p\circ \tilde \phi$ (This is where we use the hypothesis of finite sheets since $p^{-1}(A\cap U)=A\cap \cup_i U_i$). Now notice that $A\cap U_i=p|_{U_i}^{-1}(p(A)\cap U)$. And so $A\cap U_i$ will be open in $U_i$ and since $U_i$ is open it will be open in $X$. Since this is true for any $U_i$ we get that $A\cap p^{-1}(U)$ is open for any evenly covered neighborhood $U$. And so we obtain that the topologies coincide.

Any comment is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can give a CW structure on any cover(*not necessarily finite cover*) of a connected CW complex so that the covering map is cellular, and the dimension of covering is the same as the dimension of base space. Also, the construction of the proof shows that for each $n$-cell of the base space, we have exactly $k$-many $n$-cell in the cover, where $k$ is the fold of the cover.

Comment: **And this $k$ can be any non-negative integer as well as infinity.** See, for instance, [Theorem 10.43 of Rotman's Algebraic Topology](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/An_Introduction_to_Algebraic_Topology/neUlBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=rotman+algebraic+topology+theorem+10.43&pg=PA303&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Yes I knew it was true for any cover. But I wasn't able to prove it , I will look into the reference but I just wanted to see if the proof I did for the finite case is correct @Sumanta